# Read Matlab Data File into Python, Need to Export to CSV

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, scipy

I have read a Matlab file containing a large amount of arrays as a dataset into Python storing the Matlab Dictionary under the variable name `mat` using the command:

`mat = loadmat('Sample Matlab Extract.mat')`

Is there a way I can then use Python's write to csv functionality to save this Matlab dictionary variable I read into Python as a comma separated file?

```
with open('mycsvfile.csv','wb') as f:
   w = csv.writer(f)
   w.writerows(mat.items())
   f.close()
```

creates a CSV file with one column containing array names within the dictionary and then another column containing the first element of each corresponding array.  Is there a way to utilize a command similar to this to obtain all corresponding elements within the arrays inside of the 'mat' dictionary variable?

Comment: consider using HDF5, e.g. see h5py and corresponding matlab functions

Comment: how do you propose to save different variables into a single CSV file?

Comment: I was hoping there was a way to write all of the variables and their corresponding values into a type of data matrix if you will that I can then import into IBM SPSS Modeler to conduct some analysis on the data.  I was hoping to avoid iterating over the entire dictionary variable until all variables have been read because I am new to Python and know this would take a understanding of logic that I feel I don't have in the language.  Will look into understanding HDF5 and any other suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: with open('mycsvfile.csv','wb') as f:
    w = csv.writer(f)
    w.writerows(mat.items())                                        gives me a csv file with the array variable name and the first value of the array, does anyone know a way to use a command similar to this to obtain all values from the corresponding arrays in the dictionary?

Comment: Can you edit your question to contain that information?

Comment: Just did so, my apologies

Comment: As you note, `mat` is a dictionary.  `.items()` gives a (key, value) pair.  For a start, give us an idea of what `value` part of one of those `items` is like.  I'm guessing it's a `numpy.array'.  For a start try to write just one such array.  You can worry about getting them all later.

Comment: The value portion I would like to lump in with the key name is an array of numerical values, primarily floats but in some instances integers as well.  I would like to import these array names and corresponding values into SPSS Modeler for analysis.  I cannot use Modeler to import the data as a .mat file because it does not have the functionality to do so, making Python a middle ground to get the data into Modeler

Answer (score 15):

The function `scipy.io.loadmat` generates a dictionary looking something like this:

```
{'__globals__': [],
 '__header__': 'MATLAB 5.0 MAT-file, Platform: MACI, Created on: Wed Sep 24 16:11:51 2014',
 '__version__': '1.0',
 'a': array([[1, 2, 3]], dtype=uint8),
 'b': array([[4, 5, 6]], dtype=uint8)}
```

It sounds like what you want to do is make a .csv file with the keys "a", "b", etc. as the column names and their corresponding arrays as data associated with each column. If so, I would recommend using `pandas` to make a nicely formatted dataset that can be exported to a .csv file. First, you need to clean out the commentary members of your dictionary (all the keys beginning with "__"). Then, you want to turn each item value in your dictionary into a `pandas.Series` object. The dictionary can then be turned into a `pandas.DataFrame` object, which can also be saved as a .csv file. Your code would look like this:

```
import scipy.io
import pandas as pd

mat = scipy.io.loadmat('matex.mat')
mat = {k:v for k, v in mat.items() if k[0] != '_'}
data = pd.DataFrame({k: pd.Series(v[0]) for k, v in mat.items()}) # compatible for both python 2.x and python 3.x

data.to_csv("example.csv")
```

Comment: I got this error 'dict' object has no attribute 'iteritems'.

Comment: If you’re using Python 3.x, it should be .items() instead of .iteritems()

Answer (score 3):

This is correct solution for converting any .mat file into .csv file. Try it

```
   import scipy.io
   import numpy as np
   data = scipy.io.loadmat("file.mat")

   for i in data:
        if '__' not in i and 'readme' not in i:
              np.savetxt(("file.csv"),data[i],delimiter=',')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import scipy.io
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

class MatDataToCSV():

    def init(self):

        pass

    def convert_mat_tocsv(self):

        mat = scipy.io.loadmat('wiki.mat')

        instances = mat['wiki'][0][0][0].shape[1]
        columns = ["dob", "photo_taken", "full_path", "gender",\
                "name", "face_location", "face_score", "second_face_score"]
        df = pd.DataFrame(index = range(0,instances), columns = columns)

        for i in mat:
            if i == "wiki":
                current_array = mat[i][0][0]
                for j in range(len(current_array)):
                    df[columns[j]] = pd.DataFrame(current_array[j][0])
        return df
```

Answer (score 0):

reading a matfile (.MAT) with the below code
data = scipy.io.loadmat(files[0])

gives a dictionary of values and keys

and " '**header**', '**version**', '**globals**'" these are some of the default values which we need to remove

```
cols=[]
for i in data:
    if '__' not in i :
       cols.append(i)
temp_df=pd.DataFrame(columns=cols)
for i in data:
    if '__' not in i :
       temp_df[i]=(data[i]).ravel()
```

we remove the unwanted header values using "if '__' not in i:" and then make a dataframe using the rest of the headers and finally assign the column values to respective column headers